# How do I get Zlib to compress to a stream in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I’m trying to upload files to Amazon S3 using [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/doc/), but I’d like to compress them with Zlib first. AWS::S3 expects its data to be a stream object, i.e. you would usually upload a file with something like

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store('remote-filename.txt', open('local-file.txt'), 'bucket')
```

(Sorry if my terminology is off; I don’t actually know much about Ruby.) I know that I can zlib-compress a file with something like

```
data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(File.read('local-file.txt'))
```

but passing `data` as the second argument to `S3Object.store` doesn’t seem to do what I think it does. (The upload goes fine but when I try to access the file from a web browser it doesn’t come back correctly.) How do I get Zlib to deflate to a stream, or whatever kind of object `S3Object.store` wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my problem before was not that I was passing the wrong kind of thing to `S3Object.store`, but that I was generating a zlib-compressed data stream without the header you’d usually find in a `.gz` file. In any event, the following worked:

```
str = StringIO.new()
gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(str)
gz.write File.read('local-file.txt')
gz.close

AWS::S3::S3Object.store('remote-filename.txt', str.string, 'bucket')
```